# Merging two Flux streams but return only one (heartbeat)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I would like to merge two streams (one is a heartbeat to detect, that connection with client is not closed), but not to return that heartbeat to the client (some kind of filter to just return data from Kafka only). Is there a good solution to do that? Or just to detect that connection with client is closed?

I am using ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate to subscribe to the given topic. When client connects to the endpoint, then consumer starts working, but when client ends connection, its still subscribing (subscription works until Flux ends).

My code is similar to below:

```
@PostConstruct
void initialize() {
    final var properties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, TimelineNamingFactory.createTimelineGroupIdName(processInstanceId));
    ReceiverOptions<String, String> basicReceiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(properties);
    this.template = new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(
        basicReceiverOptions.subscription(
            Set.of(TimelineNamingFactory.createTimelineTopicName())
        ).closeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    );
}

@GetMapping(value = "/api/timeline:subscribe", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
Flux<String> getTimelineEvents() {
    return Flux.merge(
        template.receiveAutoAck().map(ConsumerRecord::value),
        getHeartbeatStream()
    );
}

   private Flux<String> getHeartbeatStream() {
       return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).map(i -> "ping");
   }
```

Comment: The question is unclear, are you asking about Flux.merge, filtering or handling unresponsive connection?

Comment: sorry, i would like to handle that response to be closed when client closes connection. I have found a solution, to create additional 'heartbeat' stream, which closes that connection, but results in receiving 'ping' messages. But closing connection is main problem

Comment: Not sure what set of technologies you are using, you mention kafka but I don't see how it is related with your question as you stated that your problem is to close connections with the clients, so I would asume that you are in the server side an you are trying to push data to clients using a technology with stateful connections like websockets. Response could vary a lot depending on what you are trying to implement, could you specify?

Comment: @RoberMP is right. More details are required to provide a clean solution. A quick and dirty solution could be to use [takeUntilOther](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeUntilOther-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) operator, where the "other" publisher would be `getHeartBeatStream().timeout(...).then(Mono.just("timeout"))`, or something that intercept error on the heartbeat stream, etc.

Comment: @amanin I have added some other config